# CPPUnit - Global variables

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cppunit

How can a variable that I set in first CPPUNIT_TEST be accessed in the CPPUNIT_TEST following that?

For EX.

```
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(TestingEx);
CPPUNIT_TEST(ex1);
CPPUNIT_TEST(ex2);
CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();

public:
int x=0;
void ex1()
{ 
do some testing and logic would set x to someother value ...
    x=4;
}
void ex2()
{
use x to do some testing // x should be 4, but I get 0??
}
```

Could someone please explain me what's wrong and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Cppunit follows the concept that each test is separated from each other. This is a useful assumption for all unit testing frameworks, even worse it is not guarantueed that the tests are executed in a particular order.

You have solutions to solve your problem:

- Use a static variable in your class, which is ugly and should rarely be used when writting tests and nearly never for unit tests.
- use setUp to initialize your test environment before each test is executed
- init your data in some other way like constructor, in the test method, ... before each test